# URL finder from qr code

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which scans qr code and displays the data stored in it. But I would like to open a browser whenever an URL is stored in the qr code. How to determine whether it is normal text or URL stored in the qr code.. I tried using regular  expressions or is there any other way? I used zxing library for scanning qr codes. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple. Whenever you are getting data from QR code just try as below. For valid url it will return true otherwise false.

```
 try {
      HttpURLConnection con =
         (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
      return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return false;
    }
```

Also see the link [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Answer (score 1):

First you should have a QR reader in your device, as you said you use zxing reader this code will open the app for scanning or if the user does not have the app give it a URL for downloading it in the catch:

```
try {

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); // "PRODUCT_MODE for bar codes

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

  } catch (Exception e) {

    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,marketUri);
    startActivity(marketIntent);

  }
```

and after scanning get the activity result and check the scan output in this way:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {           
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 0) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
    }
    if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        //handle cancel
    }
  }
}
```

if your out put is a URL this code will open it in device browser:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

do not miss `'http://'` in your URL, this will crash your app

happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

Use an embedded QR code reader like this app [EasyTrack] (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shipmatrix.easytrack)  What we did with this application was embedded QR Code reader, and then the application embedded utilizes it's own system of reading/acting on QR codes.

Comment: Actually I'm not looking for an  application.. I'm developing a new one.. So need ways..

Answer (score 0):

When I scan my QR code I can't open multiple websites, but by using the below code I can only open google website:

```java
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```